# swiftui alerts not showing up when notifications and activation are involved

Tags: swiftui, notifications

the below is vastly simplified code from my real code, but the issue is I can't seem to get an alert to work with notifications after activation. I want to issue a notification when the app becomes "active", and then pop up an alert.

When I start the app, the alert immediately pops up. Ok, makes sense, as the app is newly "active". And after, I iconify the app, and bring it back up. It should run into the "active" code, and it does, the below is what prints out. BUT, no alert appears at all. I can repro this on any simulator.

And I also don't get why I get "Showing alert" 3 times; I would expect it would show up only once after "Active" printed out.

And also, when I remove the notification code (and just set showAlert=true in onChange()), then sometimes I get the alert, and sometimes not. So it's not just related to notifications.

I feel like I'm missing something about how these alerts are supposed to work. Any thoughts?

```
Showing alert
Showing alert
Active
Got notification
Showing alert
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let notificationName = Notification.Name("testnotification")
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
            if newPhase == .active {
                print("Active")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil, userInfo: [:])
            }
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: notificationName)) { _ in
            showAlert = true
            print("Got notification")
        }
        .alert("HAVE AN ALERT", isPresented: $showAlert) {
            let _ = print("Showing alert")
            Button("OK", role: .cancel) {
                print("alert button pressed")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You might have to delay a little with DispatchQueue asyncAfter.

Comment: @loremipsum Yeah, that does seem to work, but also seems super kloodgy. How long to delay? In my test case I use .5 secs and that seems fine, but on real devices, across all devices...just don't know.

Comment: .5 should be fine. This is actually a known issue with SwiftUI. NotificationCenter is  one of the few things I believe go in a singleton outside of the View, I wouldn’t use onRecieve. There is a moment in between views loading and actually being able to present stuff that is why the delay is needed. Using task instead of onChange seems to manage this better

Comment: @loremipsum But how does task help? I need to know when the app has been activated, not when it appears. The task modifier only gets invoked at startup. And when you say "I wouldn't use onReceive", are you saying I shouldn't use the NotificationCenter event mechanism?

Comment: You can use task with id it will run onAppear and onChange the timing is just better, I’ve never had to delay a task. I would use Notifications the “old” way.

Comment: @loremipsum I don't see that, I only see task running when it first appears, not on subsequent activations. I don't see how using an "id" param changes anything. Only onChange() gets called. And I only know notifications the way I'm using them, I don't understand what "old" means in this context. Thx.

Comment: Use the scenePhase as the id

Comment: @loremipsum Ah ok, sorry, I didn't realize "task" was actually observing what's passed into "id". Removing onChange() and using "task" does work in my test case, w/o needing to do any timing delays. So certainly better. I am still using events as in my original.